# Edit the breadcrumb

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have pasted the following code to display a breadcrumb. But it is also displaying the the name of the site (Root).

So it looks like `sitename > home > etc..`

Please help me to remove this sitename. The code is as follows

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta ID="deltabreadcrumbnav" runat="server">-->
<!--SPM:   <div id="breadcrumbnavigation">-->
<!--SPM:     <span class="breadcrumb-nav"> -->
<!--SPM:       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder" runat="server" >-->Your Location:
<!--SPM:         <asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" id="ContentMap" SkipLinkText="" runat="server"/>-->
<!--SPM:       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--SPM:     </span>-->
<!--SPM:  </div>-->
<!--SPM:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
```

Comment: Are you ok with JavaScript solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
.s4-titletext h1{
    display:none;   
}
```

Comment: where should i add this code?

Comment: to your site css. If you don't already have a custom css file you may want to: 
-In "All files" create a folder named "styles" if it doesn't already exist.
- Make a file and name it "global.css" or w/e you want
- Edit your Master Page a file with the sufix ".master" to include your newly created css file
like:
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/SiteName/styles/Global.css" />